# What is the Quadratic equation of the below code in asymptotic analysis?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

```
int func(int n)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
          sum++;
   
   return sum;
}
```

what will be the Quadratic equation of the above code?

I know that the time complexity of this code is O(n^2), since it is of the form n(n + 1)/2. but I want to know the Quadratic equation of the complete code by analysing each line of the code.

Comment: It may be easier if you convert the `for` loops to `while` loops, e.g. `int j=1; while(j<=i) { sum++; j++; }`

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) what you mean with "quadratic equation"? Why would  `n(n + 1)/2` not fit that definition?

Comment: Wouldn't `(sum (range 1 n))` (in Clojure) be rather more concise?

Or in Java: `IntStream.range(1, n).sum();` giving O(2n).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the Quadratic equation of the complete code by analysing each line of the code.

An detailed analysis would count elementary operations which can be considered O(1).

Let's do this from the inside out:

```
sum++;
```

... is one elementary operation.

Include the inner loop:

```
for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    sum++;
```

...executes `j = 1` once, and `j <= i` is executed +1 times, and `j++` and `sum++`  times, which sums up to 1 + (+1) + 2 elementary  operations, i.e.

2 + 3

Include the outer loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        sum++;
```

...executes `i = 1` once, while `i <= n` is executed +1 times, and both `i++` and the inner loop are executed  times (with different values of ), summing up to

1 + ( + 1) +  + ∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub> (2 + 3)
elementary operations, which simplifies to:

2 + 4 + 3∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub> 
elementary operations.

Add to that the initialisation `int sum = 0`, the `return` statement, the allocation of the parameter variable, and we get something like:

5 + 4 + 3∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub> 
elementary operations.

The sum represents a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and so we can write:

5 + 4 + 3(( + 1) / 2) elementary operations.

Or as a normalized quadratic expression:

(3/2)² + (11/2) + 5 elementary operations.

For asymptotic complexity only the most significant terms need to be retained, without coefficient, so:

O(²).

Comment: You are right, @user3386109, and I'll update accordingly. Of course this will not influence the conclusion.

Comment: Agreed that it really doesn't matter, since computing an exact number of operations is silly.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this was what the asker was looking for though ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯